# Give a Specific name to column in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have following query,

```
var employees = from emp in this.DataWorkspace.v2oneboxData.me_employees
                where emp.me_is_deleted.Value == false && emp.me_is_manager == true
                select new{emp.me_first_name,emp.me_last_name,emp.me_pkey};
```

I want to give a specific name to emp.me_first_name column, just like we do in SQL Queries like:

```
select emp_first_Name as "First Name" from me_employees
```

how to do it in linq queries ???

also is it possible to combine firstName and lastname in select query in Linq ? just like we do in SQL Queries like :

```
select me_first_name + ' ' + me_last_name as 'Full Name' from me_employee
```

how can i achieve this task in linq?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make it `First Name` as that isn't a valid identifier, but you can use:

```
select new { FirstName = emp.me_first_name,
             LastName = emp.me_last_name,
             Key = emp.me_pkey };
```

Basically the property name in the anonymous type only *defaults* to whatever property you're using as the value - you can specify it yourself, but it has to be a valid C# identifier.

Or for the combination:

```
select new { FullName = emp.me_first_name + " " + emp.me_last_name,
             Key = emp.me_pkey };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var list = fro e in emp
           select new { FullName = e.Firstname + " " + e.LastName }
```

One of the example but its with the group by

[image]
Check more at : [Learn SQL to LINQ (Visual Representation)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
from emp in this.DataWorkspace.v2oneboxData.me_employees
where emp.me_is_deleted.Value == false && emp.me_is_manager == true
select new{FullName = String.Format("{0} {1}",emp.me_first_name, emp.me_last_name),emp.me_pkey};
```